# First entry from string split

Tags: r, split

I've got a column `people$food` that has entries like `chocolate` or `apple-orange-strawberry`.

I want to split `people$food` by `-` and get the first entry from the split.

In python, the solution would be `food.split('-')[0]`, but I can't find an equivalent for R.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you need to extract the first (or `nth`) entry from each split, use:

```
word <- c('apple-orange-strawberry','chocolate')

sapply(strsplit(word,"-"), `[`, 1)
#[1] "apple"     "chocolate"
```

Or faster and more explictly:

```
vapply(strsplit(word,"-"), `[`, 1, FUN.VALUE=character(1))
#[1] "apple"     "chocolate"
```

Both bits of code will cope well with selecting whichever value in the split list, and will deal with cases that are outside the range:

```
vapply(strsplit(word,"-"), `[`, 2, FUN.VALUE=character(1))
#[1] "orange" NA
```

Comment: Just as a quick aside, for non-R natives this `sapply(strsplit(word,"-"), `[`, 1)` is just plain unreadable.

Comment: I guess if you wanted to use a word instead and you were only going for a single value you could do `sapply(strsplit(word,"-"), getElement, 1)`

Comment: Using the word 'getElement' adds a LOT in terms of readability (and hence quality). Thanks

Answer (score 29):

For example

```
word <- 'apple-orange-strawberry'

strsplit(word, "-")[[1]][1]
[1] "apple"
```

or, equivalently

```
unlist(strsplit(word, "-"))[1].
```

Essentially the idea is that `split` gives a list as a result, whose elements have to be accessed either by slicing (the former case) or by unlisting (the latter).

If you want to apply the method to an entire column:

```
first.word <- function(my.string){
    unlist(strsplit(my.string, "-"))[1]
}

words <- c('apple-orange-strawberry', 'orange-juice')

R: sapply(words, first.word)
apple-orange-strawberry            orange-juice 
                "apple"                "orange"
```

Comment: `strsplit` is vectorised, so there is no need to `sapply` it over each individual item in the vector. See my answer below.

Comment: `strsplit` takes a regular expression by default, it seems. Beware.

Answer (score 26):

I would use `sub()` instead.  Since you want the first "word" before the split, we can simply remove everything after the first `-` and that's what we're left with.

```
sub("-.*", "", people$food)
```

Here's an example -

```
x <- c("apple", "banana-raspberry-cherry", "orange-berry", "tomato-apple")
sub("-.*", "", x)
# [1] "apple"  "banana" "orange" "tomato"
```

Otherwise, if you want to use `strsplit()` you can round up the first elements with `vapply()`

```
vapply(strsplit(x, "-", fixed = TRUE), "[", "", 1)
# [1] "apple"  "banana" "orange" "tomato"
```

Comment: Using `sub` function greatly simplifies the possibility of getting the first elements of even multi-dimensional lists after applying the required string patterns, thanks for the nice answer!

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest using `head` rather than `[` in R.

```
word <- c('apple-orange-strawberry','chocolate')
sapply(strsplit(word, "-"), head, 1)
# [1] "apple"     "chocolate"
```

Comment: That is a bit more readable!

Answer (score 5):

`stringr` 1.5.0 introduced [`str_split_i`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_split.html) to do this easily:

```
library(stringr)

str_split_i(c('apple-orange-strawberry','chocolate'), "-", 1)
[1] "apple"     "chocolate"
```

The third argument represents the index you want to extract. Also new is that you can use negative values to index from the right:

```
str_split_i(c('apple-orange-strawberry','chocolate'), "-", -1)
[1] "strawberry" "chocolate"
```

Answer (score 4):

`dplyr/magrittr` approach:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

word = c('apple-orange-strawberry', 'chocolate')

strsplit(word, "-") %>% sapply(extract2, 1)
# [1] "apple"     "chocolate"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `str_remove()` to delete everything after the pattern:

```
df <- data.frame(words = c('apple-orange-strawberry', 'chocolate'))

mutate(df, short = stringr::str_remove(words, "-.*")) # mutate method

stringr::str_remove(df$words, "-.*")           # str_remove example

stringr::str_replace(df$words, "-.*", "")      # str_replace method

stringr::str_split_fixed(df$words, "-", n=2)[,1]        # str_split method similar to original question's Python code

tidyr::separate(df, words, into = c("short", NA)) # using the separate function
```

> ```
>                     words       short
> 1 apple-orange-strawberry       apple
> 2               chocolate   chocolate
> ```

Answer (score -2):

Use map() function.

strsplit(string,sep)

map(strsplit(string,sep),2) #second argument of map() defines the position within the string, given 1,2 3,etc...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).