# Split one column into two : Column1-1st split and column2-rest in R

Tags: r, split, data-manipulation

my data is in a single column and I want to get the split output into 2 column.I need both output columns.

**input column is....**

### column

```
HOUSEHOLDS-Total households - Female householder- under 18 years  
Total households - Female householder- under 18 years
```

**I want the output ...**

### column1

```
HOUSEHOLDS  
Total households
```

### column2

```
Total households - Female householder- under 18 years  
Female householder- under 18 years
```

Comment: Can you add an example of the data? We need that to know on what element to split the data.

Comment: Take a look at these ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683862/first-entry-from-string-split

Comment: HOUSEHOLDS- Total households - Female householder- under 18 years 
.....
is my data.. and i want to split HOUSEHOLDS as 1st column and Total households - Female householder- under 18 years at my 2nd column.

Comment: the question is edited @PLapointe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do that with `separate` from `tidyr`. Basically, you are separating on the first occurrence of "-". The other occurrences are ignored because of `extra = "merge"`.

```
df <- read.table(text="'HOUSEHOLDS-Total households - Female householder- under 18 years'  
                      'Total households - Female householder- under 18 years'",
                       header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(tidyr)
df %>% separate(V1, into = c('Col1', 'Col2'),  sep="-", extra = "merge").
               Col1                                                  Col2
1        HOUSEHOLDS Total households - Female householder- under 18 years
2 Total households                     Female householder- under 18 years
```

Comment: it works @p lapointe .. thank you..

Answer (score 2):

if this is your dataset:

```
df1<- c("HOUSEHOLDS-Total households - Female householder- under 18 years", "Total households - Female householder- under 18 years")
```

You can use :

```
regmatches(df1, regexpr("-", df1), invert = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "HOUSEHOLDS-Total households "       "Female householder- under 18 years"

[[2]]
[1] "Total households "                   " Female householder- under 18 years"
```

The output is a list.