# Extract data from a column to create another column in R

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics, stringr

I have a data frame that has 3 variables that I would like to split into 4 variables. The data frame looks like this:

```
Species_Name    SIXTEENS_Title                           SIXTEENS_Sequence
Daphnia magna   LC382445.1 Daphnia magna mitochondrial   TTCGGAGAAAAGGGGTAC...
Daphnia magna   KY694374.1 Daphnia magna mitochondrial   TTCGGAGAAAAGGGGTAC...
```

From this data frame, under the `SIXTEENS_Title`, I want to extract everything before `Daphnia` (the alphanumerical LC382445.1, KY694374.1 ; but there are over 100 observations with different numbers).

I've tried using `str_extract()` and `str_detect()` but I can't seem to be able to do it. I want to use the accession numbers `(LC382445.1)` to create another column in R.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683862/first-entry-from-string-split

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `sub` and a regular expression.

```
df = read.table(text="Species_Name    SIXTEENS_Title         SIXTEENS_Sequence
'Daphnia magna'   'LC382445.1 Daphnia magna mitochondrial'   'TTCGGAGAAAAGGGGTAC...'
'Daphnia magna'   'KY694374.1 Daphnia magna mitochondrial'   'TTCGGAGAAAAGGGGTAC...'",
header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

sub("\\s*Daphnia.*", "", df$SIXTEENS_Title)
[1] "LC382445.1" "KY694374.1"
```